# Comment « plutôt » glisse-t-il sémantiquement pour signifier « de préférence » ?

Tags: étymologie

> [[ Wiktionnaire : ]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%B4t#fr-adv) 
>   En ancien français *tost*,
>   du latin *tostus* (« grillé, rôti, brûlé »)[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%B4t#cite_note-TLFi-1) via son accusatif neutre *tostum*, pris adverbialement ; le mot a dû signifier d'abord « chaudement » d'où « promptement »
>   → voir *tosto*, en italien.. [...]
>
> [[ Wiktionnaire : ]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plut%C3%B4t#.C3.89tymologie)
>   Du moyen français *plustost*, de l'ancien français *plus tost*.

[Le sens littéral](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plutot) (de plus tôt = bientôt), comment a-t-il changé sémantiquement pour exprimer une préférence ?

Comment: Plutôt que de « changement » sémantique, il semble préférable de parler de  « glissement » sémantique du sens de  *plus tost* signifiant « plus rapidement (que) » vers « plus volontiers que ». *Tost* a exprimé la rapidité avant d'exprimer la proximité temporelle. Si on dit à quelqu'un de venir « plus tôt », c'est bien qu'on lui dit de venir « plus vite/sans tarder ».

Comment: Ça ne répond pas directement à la question, mais je trouve intéressant que l'anglais ait aussi cette double valeur de "plus tôt" sous la forme du mot "sooner" qui peut être utilisé pour indiquer une préférence, le plus souvent pour un effet sarcastique (*I would sooner die than eat kale*)

Answer (score 1):

Comme indiqué, tôt vient de promptement (venant du latin roti, grillé, brûlé).

plutôt = plus tôt.
Il y a en fait 3 sens:

- plus vite;
- de préférence;
- passablement.

Les 2 premiers sont proches: plus rapidement, plus volontiers, d'abord, donc de préférence .... La priorité dans le temps glisse vers la priorité pour n'importe quelle raison.

puis, sans comparaison: passablement, pas mal.

voir le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plutot) :

> Adenet, Berte, éd. A. Henry, 927: eles me mengeront plus tost crue que
>   cuite.